# Difference between DeclaringType and ReflectedType

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

**Could anyone please tell the difference between these 2 Properties?**

`DeclaringType` and `ReflectedType`

Consider the code is:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method in Class", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Method in Class", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.Name);
    }
}
```

**Are these same and Can be used interchangeably?**

Comment: In case somebody is wondering *why* `ReflectedType` exists: In my opinion, it is a .NET 1.0 design mistake. They probably had a rather specific scenario in mind. I consider it to be better to keep track of the `Type` yourself instead of adding this hack to reflection objects.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

They're not exactly the same.

- `DeclaringType` returns the type that declares the method.
- `ReflectedType` returns the `Type` object that was used to retrieve the method.

Here's a demo:

```
MemberInfo m1 = typeof(Base).GetMethod("Method");
MemberInfo m2 = typeof(Derived).GetMethod("Method");

Console.WriteLine(m1.DeclaringType); //Base
Console.WriteLine(m1.ReflectedType); //Base

Console.WriteLine(m2.DeclaringType); //Base
Console.WriteLine(m2.ReflectedType); //Derived

public  class Base
{
    public void Method() {}
}

public class Derived : Base { }
```

Noticed how the last line printed `Derived` instead of `Base`. That's because, even though `Method` is *declared* on `Base`, we used `Derived` to obtain the `MemberInfo` object.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Compare the example from the question, and note that if you make a call to `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` inside the `Method()` inside `Base`, and then calls that method on an instance of `Derived` (as in `new Derived().Method();`),  you do ***not*** get `m2` as you may have hoped. You get `m1`. That is something to be aware of.

Comment: In the same light as the previous comment, methods retrieved from a StackFrame (vi StackTrace) through GetMethod also lose out on the 'reflected' bit..

Comment: It might be worth noting that methods overridden in the derived type are considered declared in the derived type, not in the base type. IOW, if `Base` would override `Method`, both the `DeclaringType` and `ReflectedType` for `Derived.Method` would be the same.

Comment: @ZevSpitz `Method` already is a native member of `Base`. `Base` wouldn't override it. That is true if `Derived` would override it.

Comment: @Suncat2000 That's what I probably meant -- if `Derived` has an overriding `Method`.

Comment: For future visitors: The existence of `ReflectedType` is an awful (in my mind senseless) design error, and it's gone on .NET Core. See https://web.archive.org/web/20160429093051/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kingces/archive/2005/08/01/446247.aspx.

Comment: @usr, what do you mean by "gone"? I'm seeing it in .NET 6.